# Django form not saving password when creating user

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have made a custom form for my django app which allows users to register themselves for the website.

This is the form for my django app:

```
class TeacherRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True)
    school = forms.CharField(required = True)
    subject = forms.CharField(required = True)
    head_of_subject = forms.BooleanField(required = False)
    identification_code = forms.CharField(required = True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TeacherRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].help_text = ''
        self.fields['password2'].help_text = ''


    class Meta:
        model = User

        fields = (
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'school',
            'identification_code',
            'subject',
            'head_of_subject',
            'password1',
            'password2'            
        )

    def save(self, request):
        form = TeacherRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        user = User.objects.create(first_name=self.cleaned_data['first_name'],
                            last_name=self.cleaned_data['last_name'],
                            email=self.cleaned_data['email'],
                            username=self.cleaned_data['username'],
                            password=self.cleaned_data['password1']
                            )

        teacher_profile = TeacherProfile.objects.create(user=user,
                                                        school=self.cleaned_data['school'],
                                                        subject=self.cleaned_data['subject'],
                                                        head_of_subject=self.cleaned_data['head_of_subject'],
                                                        )


        return user, teacher_profile
```

This is the relevant part of the view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':

        form = TeacherRegistrationForm(request.POST)

        entered_school_name = form['school'].value()
        entered_school_id = form['identification_code'].value()

        actual_school_id = SchoolProfile.objects.get(school_name__exact = entered_school_name).identification_code

        if form.is_valid()and (entered_school_id == actual_school_id):

            user, teacher_profile = form.save(request)

            return render(request, 'accounts/home.html')
        else:
            args = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'accounts/reg_form.html', args)
```

When I press submit, the user is created, however no password is set for the user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to touch any of the fields that are part of User, and in fact you shouldn't do that but instead let the UserCreationForm handle it because there's some special handling for password in there.

Do it like so, in your form class save method:

```
def save(self):
    user = super(TeacherRegistrationForm, self).save()
    teacher_profile = TeacherProfile(
        user=user,
        school=self.cleaned_data['school'],
        subject=self.cleaned_data['subject'],                   
        head_of_subject=self.cleaned_data['head_of_subject']
    )
    teacher_profile.save()
    return user, teacher_profile
```

This will result in the TeacherRegistrationForm, which is a subclass of UserCreationForm, which is in turn a subclass of ModelForm.. will do what ModelForm is supposed to do, which is to save itself to the database (user table) when you call its save method.  So that's all done for you.  Then you just have to handle the extra fields you added to the form for the other model.

And notice I used the model `save()` method instead of using `create()`, which in this case accomplishes the same thing..  but you could later on modify the form code to allow the same form to edit an existing model not just create a new one.  Let me know if you would like me to explain that too.

Comment: I understand what you mean for the most part. Basically because ModelForm will handle all the default fields, I don't need to tell it to save them, and therefore don't need part of my code. And using save() will allow me to update the user when I come to make my edit page? Is that all right?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's how it works.  The ModelForm save method will save any fields that exist in the model it is based on (in this case `User`) and you only have to deal with the additional fields. As far as updates vs.inserts, in order to to an update you have to pass the instance you want to update into the constructor of the ModelForm.  I am on cellphone right now but I'll update my answer in the morning to show a form that can do either insert or update.

Answer (score 1):

Try editing your form like this,

```
def save(self): 
    user = User.objects.create_user(username=self.cleaned_data['username'], password=self.cleaned_data['password1']) 
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    user.save()
    teacher_profile = TeacherProfile.objects.create(user=user, school=self.cleaned_data['school'], subject=self.cleaned_data['subject'], head_of_subject=self.cleaned_data['head_of_subject'] ) 
    return user, teacher_profile
```

Use `User.objects.create_user()` rather than `objects.create`.

I don't see the point of passing`request` into the save method. You can remove that part. `save` method is called when `form.save()` is executed. Also, saving form again in the form save method is actually unnecessary.

Comment: Getting an error in my views "TypeError at /users/register save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" 
`user, teacher_profile = form.save(request) `

EDIT: Managed to get it to work! Thanks for the help

Comment: No need of save user in custom way because UserCreationForm has logic that can create user with password set and validations

Comment: This is not the right way to do it.. there's no need to explicitly set first_name or any of those user fields.

Answer (score 0):

No need of save user in custom way, you inherited `UserCreationForm` that will return user instance after set password and with validation So you will get direct user instance in super call.

```
def save(self, request):       
   user = super(TeacherRegistrationForm, self).save()
   teacher_profile = TeacherProfile.objects.create(user=user,                                         
                      school=self.cleaned_data['school'], 
                      subject=self.cleaned_data['subject'],                                                            
                      head_of_subject=self.cleaned_data['head_of_subject'],
                    )
   return user, teacher_profile
```